# Ng-repeat is not working as expected in html table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

Why doesn't this simple table structure work in angularjs? None of the rows gets populated with the data. If I replace **span** with **tr**, it works fine but my third column of **Percent** doesn't fit in well.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
 <tbody>
    <tr>
         <th>Grade</th>
         <th>Point</th>
         <th>Percent</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
          <span ng-repeat="gdata in gradepoints">
             <td ng-repeat="(grade, gp) in gdata"> {{grade | uppercase}} </td>
             <td ng-repeat="(grade, gp) in gdata"> {{gp}} </td>
           </span>
           <span ng-repeat="pdata in percents">
              <td ng-repeat="(grade, perc) in pdata"> {{perc}} </td>
           </span>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: please supply some sample data, it's hard to see what you're trying to do, but I assume you have two arrays, gdata and pdata, and that gdata[0] corresponds to the grade and gp of the same percent in pdata[0], etc.  Is that right?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat actually i've re-architectured and simplified my api and hence the json, so this problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="gdata in gradepoints">
    <td>{{gdata.grade | uppercase}}</td>
    <td>{{gdata.gp}}</td>
    <td>{{pdata[$index].perc</td>
</tr>
```

You want one row for each element in the gdata array, so the ng-repeat needs to be on the `<tr>` element.  If the two arrays aren't in sync, you can create a function in your controller to return the pdata element you need:

```
$scope.findPdata(gdata, index) {
    // ... do your magic here to find the pdata element you want
    return result;
}

<td>{{findPdata(gdata, $index)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

guessing from the below:

```
        <tr>
                  <th>Grade</th>
                 <th>Point</th>
                  <th>Percent</th>
       </tr>
```

i guess your table has 3 columns so your each row has 3 columns?

in that case use the following

```
<tr ng-repeat="gdata in gradepoints">

  <td>{{gdata.grade | uppercase}}</td>
 <td>{{gdata.gp}}</td>
   <td>{{gdata.percent}}</td>


</tr>
```

for above to work your gradepoints must be an ARRAY containing objects with 3 properties each i.e. grade,gp,percent

Comment: Yes 3 columns. gradepoints and percents are two different arrays.

Comment: if you can post the arrangement of gradepoints object with sample data i would be happy to help